# How to open an image from C using a system call in windows?

Tags: c, windows

I have this very simple code to display an image file. It works fine in mac. How to do something similar for windows? What do I need to use in the system function call? I'm using cygwin, btw.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int nargs, char *argv[])
{   system("open image.png");       //  display image on mac previewer

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The closest equivalent for Windows is probably [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

Comment: Have you tried system("mspaint image.png");?

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff Well, that works fine to open the image with paint, but I want to open it with the default image viewer. Imagine it like what happens when you double click the image. Which the instruction for that will be?

Comment: May be you could search in the registry the program associeted with the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Windows API in cygwin. You can then use `ShellExecute` (it needs `"Shell32.lib"`)

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int nargs, char *argv[])
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "c:\\path\\image.png", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `Sleep` is optional. In some Windows versions `ShellExecute` fails if the program returns immediately.

See also [Using Win32 API in Cygwin applications](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32-api)

Comment: I tested it, but this happened:

sh: start: order not found

no clue what is wrong